# a C code that runs a grocery list thru an array of predefined items and then identifies each item, adds the price and calculates total bill

Tags: c, project

I am writing this for an assignment at college, The topic is "Supermarket Bill" no elaboration. The teacher is expecting a code thats simple and easy to use. I wanted to create a code that would firstly display a list of things that the user could buy, then the user will enter some items, then the code will compare the input with the items in the array and add a total of 100 in the bill for each item identified. I am making the cost of everything 100 for simplicity.

Till now I have written this code, but it only takes input of one item and gives total bill as 100 then.

```
int main()
{
   #define MAX_STRING_SIZE 40
   #define N 15

 char arr[N][MAX_STRING_SIZE] =
{ "sugar",
  "tea",
  "salt",
  "spices",
  "bread",
  "butter",
  "milk",
  "flour",
  "rice",
  "pulses",
  "tomato",
  "potato",
  "eggs",
  "apples",
  "bananas"
  };
  
  char item[20];
  int bill=0;
  int i;
  printf("Enter the items you want to buy, press q to quit ");
  scanf("%s",&item);
  
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
       if(strcmp(arr[i], item) == 0)
      {
        printf("\n\tFound %s.", item);
        bill=bill+100;
      }
     
   }
      printf("\n\tTotal cost= Rs. %d ", bill);
    return 0;
}
```

I then put it in a while loop with q to quit but it keeps going on and on. Adding a break doesnt work either.

```
 while (strcmp (item, "q") != 0)
  {
      for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
       if(strcmp(arr[i], item) == 0)
      {
        printf("Found %s.", item);
        break;
        bill=bill+100;
      }
   }
  }
```

I dont know how to make it take multiple inputs and strcmp all of them one by one thru the array and then add prices. Help?

Comment: Homework questions are meant to be solved on your own :)

Comment: `while (strcmp (item, "q") != 0)`. Ask yourself, how does that ever become true considering there is no `scanf` (or any other input read) in the loop to change the `item` string? Now would be a good time to learn to do basic debugging of your own code. Start your program in a debugger and trace it as it runs.

Comment: @kaylum OMG i got it what you wanted me to do and i edited it and it works beautifully! thank you so much!! hehe do you want to see?

Comment: @Shaunak lmao i had a little doubt, and i also solved it on my own now with the help of the hint by kaylum

Comment: @AlexaMau good for you!

Comment: @AlexaMau I don't need to see it but you can post an answer to your own question if you like.